# Error when i want to use model dart file in main code

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile

I'm creating a quiz game with flutter .
Everything was working fine until today.
I created a question_model dart file in model directory in lib for questions .
In this model file , i have a question List that i write the questions in there.
Everytime that i want to use this questionList it gaves me this error :
Undefined name 'questionList'

It's my questionList which located in /lib/model/question_model:

```
`class Question {
  String question;

  String answer1;

  String answer2;

  int trueAnswer;

  String imageAddress;

  Question(this.question, this.answer1, this.answer2, this.trueAnswer,
      this.imageAddress);

  List<Question> questionList = [
    Question('Where is Persian Gulf?', 'Iran', 'Iraq', 1,
        'assets/images/persiangulf.png'),
    Question('Which one is most population country in the world?', 'India',
        'China', 2, 'assets/images/most.png'),
    Question('Which one created GTA series?', 'Ubisoft', 'Rockstar', 1,
        'assets/images/GTA.png'),
    Question('Which one is a rock band?', 'Queen', 'Metallica', 1,
        'assets/images/guitar.png'),
  ];

}`
```

And this is how i want to use this List :

```
`checkAnswer(){
    setState(() {});
    int myAnswer = isOnePressed?1:2;
    questionList[currentQuestionNumber];
  }`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An approach would be to declare the question list as static and then use it outside using reference. To do this you can update your code as follows:

```
 static List<Question> questionList = [
    Question('Where is Persian Gulf?', 'Iran', 'Iraq', 1, 'assets/images/persiangulf.png'),
    Question('Which one is the most populous country in the world?', 'India', 'China', 2, 'assets/images/most.png'),
    Question('Which one created the GTA series?', 'Ubisoft', 'Rockstar', 1, 'assets/images/GTA.png'),
    Question('Which one is a rock band?', 'Queen', 'Metallica', 1, 'assets/images/guitar.png'),
  ];
```

and then reference it in your function in the following way

```
checkAnswer() {
  setState(() {});
  int myAnswer = isOnePressed ? 1 : 2;
  Question.questionList[currentQuestionNumber];
}
```

You may also declare the list outside the question class. That way you donot need to modify anything except for cutting the list out of question class and pasting it down below it.